# Select query to show missing values per day as 0

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have one table with product id's and another with daily data for these products. When there is no data I want to return 0 instead of no value at all. I tried using a left join but this doesn't give the resultset I want since the table I can join on has product id's only, not per day.

I guess I have to generate a table first with all products for all dates and then join my data on that. Not sure how to construct this though.

Example of the products table:

```
id - product
1 - test1
2 - test2
3 - test3
```

example of the daily data:

```
product - date - value
test1 - 2020-01-01 - 10
test2 - 2020-01-01 - 8
test3 - 2020-01-01 - 9
test1 - 2020-01-02 - 9
test3 - 2020-01-02 - 10
test2 - 2020-01-03 - 6
test3 - 2020-01-03 - 5
```

Result I'm looking for:

```
product - date - value
test1 - 2020-01-01 - 10
test2 - 2020-01-01 - 8
test3 - 2020-01-01 - 9
test1 - 2020-01-02 - 9
test2 - 2020-01-02 - 0
test3 - 2020-01-02 - 10
test1 - 2020-01-03 - 0
test2 - 2020-01-03 - 6
test3 - 2020-01-03 - 5
```

Comment: Have a recursive cte or help calendar table returning all wanted dates. outer join.

Comment: There are ways to code around this, but to reinforce @jarlh's comment, you should do some research and build yourself a calendar table if you don't already have one. It makes tasks like this trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cross join` to get the rows and then `left join` to bring in the data you want:

```
select p.id, c.date, coalesce(d.value, 0) as value
from products p cross join
     (select distinct date from daily) c left join
     daily d
     on d.product = p.id and d.date = c.date;
```

If there are dates that are not in the table, you can generate the dates using `generate_series()`:

```
select p.id, c.date, coalesce(d.value, 0) as value
from products p cross join
     (select generate_series(min(d.date), max(d.date), interval '1 day') as date
      from daily
     ) c left join
     daily d
     on d.product = p.id and d.date = c.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yuo could use a subquery and cross join for find the missing combination

```
select p.product, d.date, ifnull(value,0)
from  (
  select distinct p.produtc, d.date 
  from product 
  cross join date 
) t 
inner join product p on t.product = d.product
inner  join  data d on t.date = d.date
```